# Import .png files into separate layers of a PSD file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is it possible to import a batch of .png files into a PSD, such that each imported .png is in a separate layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File > Scripts > Load Files Into Stack`

A dialog window pops up, click the <kbd>Browse</kbd> button and navigate to your files, select them and click <kbd>Open</kbd>. Then click the <kbd>Okay</kbd> button and each image file should be loaded as a layer into a Photoshop document.