# How to export slices to PSD in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, cs5, photoshop-scripting, slices

I have a big PSD file with many slices, and I would like to have all those slices in new separate PSD files.

Is there a way to export a slice to a PSD ? And automate this action using a script/action ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Would exporting all the slices with save for web and then making a new document and importing those images as a stack work? See how to import multiple images [Import .png files into separate layers of a PSD file?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28672/import-png-files-into-separate-layers-of-a-psd-file)

Comment: @AndrewH although interesting, your solution doesn't allow to keep the layer structure of the file. This is the process I'd like to automatize:


1/ Select the slice using Rectangular marquee tool


2/ Image > Crop


3/ File > Save As... > Layers/As a copy


4/ Go back to original PSD and revert the crop.

Comment: I'm now using Photoshop CC but the question remains :)

Comment: because of how the slice tool is used, I am unsure of how you can save a slice as an image (tiff/psd) with layers. The only process I am aware of is the one you mentioned about cropping the selected slice and then saving as an image format that supports layers. My only other thought would be to open the PSD in Illustrator and save move the slices to there own artboards. One feature to look out for is Photoshop CC is getting artboards soon (just saw a demo video yesterday). So I think this would resolve your issue when it comes out in an update.

Comment: Wow, this feature would really come in handy! In the meantime, we're also using Illustrator. Thanks again Andrew!

Comment: Just wondering why you want them all saved as PSD?

Comment: Also, According to one of your comments, do you actually need to use slices? You could easily use "Export > Layers to files" and it will save each layer in it's own file without slices.  It will just crop to the transparent pixel if you save as .png.  If you save as PSD - you can run a batch action after you save layers as files to crop to transparent pixels

Comment: hi @ntgCleaner, I've been using slices because the document was formatted that way. I guess graphic artists are now using layers instead.

Comment: @Charlie, yep. Slices are very, very old school now. Just design the page as you normally would. If your design requires saving more than icons and pictures, it'll probably be too heavy for today's modern web design. Slices went out of style with "web 2.0". But I definitely understand doing what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Open the "Save For Web" dialogue by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. In left panel you'll see the Slice Select Tool. Select and save it, they will be saved in a folder named images.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Make a selection & convert it to a smart object (all of the selection will be converted to a smart object), then right click on the smart object to export its content. You are done.

Comment: Make selection = select layer? or select slice? Can you edit your answer to make it more clear? This doesn't seem like a good solution.